# How do I separately change left and right volumes using pactl?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

The pactl man page claims that separate channel volumes can be set by simply listing the volume for each (and every) channel, using the set-sink-volume command:

```
set-sink-volume SINK VOLUME [VOLUME ...]
              Set the volume of the specified sink (identified by its symbolic
              name or numerical index). VOLUME can be specified as an  integer
              (e.g.  2000,  16384),  a linear factor (e.g. 0.4, 1.100), a per‐
              centage (e.g. 10%, 100%) or a decibel value (e.g. 0dB, 20dB). If
              the  volume specification start with a + or - the volume adjust‐
              ment will be relative to the current sink volume. A single  vol‐
              ume  value  affects  all channels; if multiple volume values are
              given their number has to match the sink's number of channels.
```

But as far as I can tell, this doesn't work.

This works:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 125%
```

but this does not:

```
pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 125% 100%
```

and gives this error message: `You have to specify a sink name/index and a volume`

I can set separate volumes with pavucontrol, so I know the hardware is capable.  (The hardware is a "$9 computer" CHIP device, for what it's worth.)

Is there a syntactical trick I'm missing, to get pactl to accept left and right volumes?

BTW, the pacmd man page doesn't imply that it can set channel volumes separately -- the behavior it documents is much like what I observe with pactl.  But I can't use or test pacmd, because it won't work with a pulseaudio server running in "system" mode, as mine is.

For completeness, the output of "list sinks" (after using pavucontrol to set separate volumes) is:

```
Sink #0
        State: RUNNING
        Name: alsa_output.platform-1c22c00.codec.analog-stereo
        Description: sun4i-codec Analog Stereo
        Driver: module-alsa-card.c
        Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
        Channel Map: front-left,front-right
        Owner Module: 1
        Mute: no
        Volume: front-left: 92572 / 141% / 9.00 dB,   front-right: 65944 / 101% / 0.16 dB
                balance -0.29
        Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
        Monitor Source: alsa_output.platform-1c22c00.codec.analog-stereo.monitor
        Latency: 25624 usec, configured 26000 usec
        Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
        Properties:
                alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
                device.api = "alsa"
                device.class = "sound"
                alsa.class = "generic"
                alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
                alsa.name = ""
                alsa.id = "CDC PCM Codec-0"
                alsa.subdevice = "0"
                alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
                alsa.device = "0"
                alsa.card = "0"
                alsa.card_name = "sun4i-codec"
                alsa.long_card_name = "sun4i-codec"
                alsa.driver_name = "sun4i_codec"
                device.bus_path = "platform-1c22c00.codec"
                sysfs.path = "/devices/platform/soc@01c00000/1c22c00.codec/sound/card0"
                device.string = "hw:0"
                device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
                device.buffering.fragment_size = "58800"
                device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
                device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
                device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
                device.description = "sun4i-codec Analog Stereo"
                module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
                device.icon_name = "audio-card"
        Ports:
                analog-output: Analog Output (priority: 9900)
        Active Port: analog-output
        Formats:
                pcm
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, because the question was invalid:  I neglected to take into account that the version of pulseaudio running on my embedded board is ancient.  From the githup pulseaudio repo, it looks like this bug was probably fixed many years ago.

If I run remotely from my device, using a current version of pactl, everything works as it should.